# Geting string <atribute> = <value> from xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a question, if there is code to read settings from xml, like:

```
<length>5</length>
<height>10</heigth>
```

How I can get in C#

```
for (i = 0; i < atributesInFile; i++)
{
   <atribute> = <atribute>.innertext;
}
```

So it would be like

```
length = 5;
height = 10;
```

I hope you get my point :)

Comment: Can you show valid XML.

Comment: What do you mean, do you really want to dynamically create local variables based on the XML? That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Point is, when I have many settings, and I would like to make it in short with code like reading it with loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a class which represents the XML:

```
    public class MyType
    {
      public int Height { get; set; }
      public int Length { get; set; }
    }
```

Then do this:

```
      var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (MyType));
      using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(@"location"))
      {
          var myType = (MyType) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
      }
```

Comment: I don't understand, why does your code deserialize the XML and then overwrite the read values?

Comment: That wasn't the important part.. just wanted to show that you can work with strongly typed types.

Answer (score 0):

If your XML is like this

```
<settings>
 <length>5</length>
 <height>10</height>
</settings>
```

you can do

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(pathtoxml);

foreach (var setting in xdoc.Descendants("settings"))
{
 var line = setting.Name + " = " + setting.Value + ";";
 // display line
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. Some code formatting issues with my browser.. Assume a settings element encompassing your xml